# In spring security how to do multiple authentication based on header

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring app that has been integrated with SAML authentication. But now I wanted to expose my api's to other applications and third-party system for which I am using token based authentication. So, how can I check based on the header which authentication mechanism to choose. If the header has `X-Apikey` as header then need to apply header-based authentication where token must be checked by calling a rest api result(authentication & authorization server). If the token is not having `X-Apikey` header then need to perform SAML authentication. How can I achieve this with already integrated SAML App.

Comment: I assume it can be achieved by adding filter that checks API key header before SAML security filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use a CustomFilter you add in the

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            ...
            .addFilter(customBeforeAuthenticationFilter, CustomBeforeAuthenticationFilter.class)
            ...
}
```

here more details: https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security

2) Alternative is adding a "AuthenticationManagerResolver" in your security filter you can then check the headers and decide the authentication used

here is a guide: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authenticationmanagerresolver

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [AuthenticationManagerResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.2/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManagerResolver.html). You can customize at runtime which authentication logic to apply based on a Context (typically an HttpRequest).
See this [example](https://mflash.dev/blog/2020/11/15/protecting-endpoints-with-spring-security-resource-server/) and here is a [dedicated presentation](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/authenticationmanagerresolver/)